# Cant loop Repeater Goup Fields, on liquid shopify theme

Tags: shopify, liquid

Im developing a shopify theme using liquid and Adivanced Custom Fields App. I have assigned a meta group field to a page called faq. Im tying to loop this field but without any sucess. One of the problems is that I cant assingn any key or Namespace to the group field, but only a title. What should I do?

```
{% for field in page.metafields %}
  {% if field.title == "Repeater Group Title" %}
    {% for item in field.value %}
      <h2>{{ item.field1 }}</h2>
      <p>{{ item.field2 }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to share more information about how you set up these in the backend.

Comment: @Onkar
 Thank you, I have added more details.